# Is the use of "then" wrong in "it has been around for much more then ten years"?

Tags: word-usage

There are lots of explanations here and there, including [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31363/difference-between-then-and-than), that let me think the answer is yes, it is wrong. However, I'm currently reading the preface of a PDF book and in a few lines I've encountered three times the word "**then**" with the feeling it should have been "**than**". Since the book seems quite serious, I can't really believe that an error like this could be in the very first sentences of the preface, hence the question.

Extract from [Object-oriented Programming with ANSI-C](http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/ooc.pdf):

> Object-oriented programming is the current cure-all — although it has been
>   around for much more **then** ten years. At the core, there is little more to it **then**
>   finally applying the good programming principles which we have been taught for
>   more **then** twenty years.

Do we agree that the word **then** that appears three times in bold in this citation is wrongly used and should be replaced by **than**?

If we do, could you see a reason why **then** is used instead of **than** ? Could it be some sort of local variance?

Comment: This is either three mistakes or three typos in a row.

Comment: Ouch. Don't buy that book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In all three cases, it's either a typo, or someone is very wrong in their use of *than*.

We don't have to get to the meanings to find out the mistake. *than* is a **preposition** and sometimes a **conjunction**. *then* is almost always an **adverb**. All your empty slots, should we have been filling them with either *then* or *than*, require a preposition.

If we resort to meaning, *than* is used to demonstrate contrast.

> For years, people have been trying to be **more** awesome **than** me.

*then* either refers to a specific time

> Obviously, we did things right back **then**.

or is used for introducing subsequence.

> **Then**, I tried to convince him that I'm wrong.

Mistaking *than* for *then* or the vice versa is not uncommon on the 'Net, notably.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I'm used to seeing multiple mistakes on the 'Net but I have a high trust factor in the grammar of the books I read, including this kind of document. I'll mail the author :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely a very sloppy mistake. **Then** and **than**, while similar looking and sounding words, have totally different meanings, and should never be substituted for one another.

However, it's a relatively common mistake in casual usage, especially on the internet, and especially when taking dictation. A number of accents and dialects reduce the vowel sound in both words.

It's normally caught by even a simple context-sensitive grammar checker, suggesting that this book was not very well edited.